# Remove plus sign from url using .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My current url is:

```
http://localhost/mywbsite/search/one+piece/149
```

I want to change link to like this

```
http://localhost/mywbsite/search/one-piece/149
```

I have already .htaccess file with this code

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /indianrealitybytes/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search_advance\.php\?keywords=([^&]+)&f=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ search/%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ search_advance.php?keywords=$1&f=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

I don't know where to change to remove plus(+) sign to dash (-) sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new rule for `+/-` conversion:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /indianrealitybytes/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search_advance\.php\?keywords=([^&]+)&f=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ search/%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^+]*)\+(.*)$ $1-$2 [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ search_advance.php?keywords=$1&f=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: thax for the help bro